# Tensorflow qunatization - what does zero point mean

Tags: tensorflow, quantization

I am trying to understand quantization in tensorflow and I am following this tutorial.

https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/8-bit-quantization-and-tensorflow-lite-speeding-up-mobile-inference-with-low-precision-a882dfcafbbd

In the tutorial it says that, the quantization equation is:

[image]

- r is the real value (usually float32)
- q is its quantized representation as a B-bit integer (uint8, uint32, etc.)
- S (float32) and z (uint) are the factors by which we scale and shift the number line. z is the quantized ‘zero-point’ which will always map back exactly to 0.f.

I am struggling to understand the meaning of the zero point and was hoping somebody could explain it with an example?

Answer (score 12):

If your original data has negative values, then a zero point can offset the range, allowing you to store them in an unsigned integer. So if your zero point was 128, then unscaled negative values -127 to -1 could be represented by 1 to 127, and positive values 0 to 127 could be represented by 128 to 255. Note the quantized value of 0 (or input -128 here) is intentionally unused to keep range symmetry on both ends, hence a total range of 256-1 values instead of 256. Then larger real values can be mapped using the scale factor.

e.g. Given an input tensor with data ranging from -1000 to +1000 (inclusive both ends), and an element in it with value 39.215686275, that element's quantized value would be 133 when using 128 as the zero point:

```py
quantizedValue = round(realValue    / scale       + quantizedZeroPoint)
##               round(39.215686275 / 7.843137255 + 128               ) = 133
##               round(0            / 7.843137255 + 128               ) = 128
##               round(1000         / 7.843137255 + 128               ) = 255
##               round(-1000        / 7.843137255 + 128               ) = 1
```

Using:

```py
## Determine the maximum range of the data (either known or via reduce min/max):
realRangeMinValue = -1000
realRangeMaxValue =  1000

## Use a zero point halfway between the quantized data type range.
## Note 256/2 is symmetric, with 127 on either side, as q=0 isn't really used.
quantizedRange         = 2^8 - 1 = 255
quantizedRangeMinValue = 1
quantizedRangeMaxValue = 255
quantizedZeroPoint     = 128

## Precompute scale, using the same zero point and scale for the entire tensor.
scale = (realRangeMaxValue - realRangeMinValue) / quantizedRange
##    = (1000              - -1000            ) / 255
##    = 7.843137255
##
## Alternately, you could precompute the inverse scale and multiply rather than divide
## (inverseScale = 0.1275).
```

Conversely from quantized value to real:

```py
realValue = (quantizedValue - quantizedZeroPoint) * scale
##          (133            - 128               ) * 7.843137255 =  39.215686275
##          (128            - 128               ) * 7.843137255 =  0
##          (255            - 128               ) * 7.843137255 =  1000
##          (1              - 128               ) * 7.843137255 = -1000
```